# To show more categories in Outlook Categorize drop down menu?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Microsoft Outlook "Categorize" menu, there are 15 categories listed. Is it possible to configure it to show more, such as 30?

Comment: If it's possible at all, it would be a Registry setting

Comment: The maximum number colors 1s 25 but you can have as many categories as you wish with maximum of 25 colors.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36974a3f-6b62-49c6-89ba-3487a4ba05da/max-number-of-categories?forum=outlook#:~:text=The%20colors%20are%20limited%20to,like%20with%20the%20same%20color.

Comment: @JW0914 i also think so

Comment: @John i'm referring to Categories, not their colors.

Comment: Outlook can use many categories - more than 15 by quite a bit.  But the total colors for as many categories as needed is 25.

Comment: @John I think you're misunderstanding what athos is referring to, which is the number of quick select categories shown when clicking/mousing over Categories in the context menu/Categories column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid that we could not add more than 15 categories in the list just as @Perry mentioned in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1386332/outlook-categories-not-appearing-in-drop-down-menu). We need to click "All Categories" to choose those categories not listed in the drop down menu and you can also get them via custom shortcuts.